# Retrieve all objects with errors from model on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There's an easy why that I don't remember to retrieve all invalid objects saved in the database from rails console.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

say your model is called Widget, then:

```
Widget.all.select(&:invalid?)
```

That's likely to be very slow if you have a lot of data, but you have to retrieve the records from the database if you want to check their validity.

Comment: This solution isn't efficient at all. You're better off using `#find_each` instead which is pulls the records from the database in batch. It will use less resources.

Comment: actually, this pulls every record in shot which is as efficient as possible, assuming the machine has enough memory.  The inefficiency arises from the fact you have to actually retrieve the objects to check their validity.  Sure `#find_each` might be useful in some cases, but the OP asked "to retrieve all invalid objects saved in the database", not how to retrieve all in batches.

Comment: `#all` is actually very inefficient. Doing `Widget.find_each(&:invalid?)` will yield the same result as your solution but will instead pull the records from the database in batch instead of all at once. Your solution isn't wrong, just a performance hitter that's all.